# UITableview Section - How to recalculate the height properly?

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, kingfisher

Video:

https://youtu.be/sSHrxSIHUM4

As you can see in video the issue I got. The image height constraint was broken cause the label missing height as well. They're in the section of tableview (class `UITableHeaderFooter`). I used `automaticDimension` to calculate its height and the result is corrected.

This is the image view constraint. (default height constraint is 184 and to be updated at the runtime depend on the ratio.)

https://uphinhnhanh.com/image/SAezyz

And the label constraint:

https://uphinhnhanh.com/image/SAeT5Y

The issue happened after I called `table reload` to reconfigure the section view data and height then downloading the image. I got the broken constraint warning. Xcode broke the imageview height constraint that cause the problem.

```
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2807252c0 UIImageView:0x109c002d0.height == 735.885   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280727160 UIImageView:0x109c007f0.height == 40   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280715900 UIView:0x109c00d10.height == 51   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2807140f0 UILayoutGuide:0x281d7e680'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.bottom == UIView:0x109c00d10.bottom   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2807174d0 V:|-(11)-[UIImageView:0x109c007f0]   (active, names: '|':engie_up.PostDetailHeaderView:0x109c00000 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280717c50 V:[UIImageView:0x109c007f0]-(18.5)-[engie_up.KwExpandableContextLabel:0x10491c600'bfbfnff']   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280715130 V:[engie_up.KwExpandableContextLabel:0x10491c600'bfbfnff']-(18)-[UIImageView:0x109c002d0]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280714fa0 V:[UIImageView:0x109c002d0]-(0)-[UIView:0x109c00d10]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28072ad00 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' engie_up.PostDetailHeaderView:0x109c00000.height == 343   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2807179d0 'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide-bottom' V:[UILayoutGuide:0x281d7e680'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide']-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':engie_up.PostDetailHeaderView:0x109c00000 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2807252c0 UIImageView:0x109c002d0.height == 735.885   (active)>
```

I notice that the `'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height'` is the estimate height.

The fetching code is simple since I utilize the Kingfisher

```
let ratio = CGFloat(image.width) / CGFloat(image.height)
userContentImageViewHeightConstraint.constant = CGFloat((UIScreen.main.bounds.width) / ratio)
self.userContentImageView.kf.indicatorType = .activity
self.userContentImageView.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: image.url), completionHandler: { (_, _, _, _) in
     self.setNeedsLayout()
     self.layoutIfNeeded()
     })
```

So I want to ask how can I fix the constraint breaking properly ?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the visual appearance of your View? Can you add screenshot of what you have made and what you want to made?

Comment: @SyedQamarAbbas, I have uploaded the video. You can see the label is missing when I scroll down and the image is shrinked and stretched.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I removed the image height constraint and added a aspect ratio constraint, the breaking now gone but got same result in the video

```
        let ratio = CGFloat(image.width) / CGFloat(image.height)
        let constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.userContentImageView,
                                            attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.width,
                                            relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal,
                                            toItem: self.userContentImageView,
                                            attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.height,
                                            multiplier: ratio,
                                            constant: 0.0)
        constraint.priority = 999
        self.userContentImageViewAspectConstraint = constraint
```

**Update 2: Jan 18, 2019**

Finally, I found the root cause of issue.
I didnt notice that the bottom view's bottom constraint is aligned to the Safe Area Layout. That causes at the beginning, the view is kind of pulled up above the tabbar, and that generated an extra space and breaking the image constraint's height (its priority is 999). I changed it align to the super view then issue gone.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked again your attached screenshots. Everything looks good to me. Now I'm still taking quite a guess here. Normally when such constraints warning happens, even if it takes my time, I'd solve it. It's nice that you have already the data image size.

From this block of code:

```
self.userContentImageView.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: image.url), completionHandler: { (_, _, _, _) in
     self.setNeedsLayout()
     self.layoutIfNeeded()
     })
```

That's ugly and would definitely make a flickering or unwanted animation/movement bug, like in your video demo.

Usually, to me, the `self.layoutIfNeeded()` would suffice to adjust the layout AFTER adjusting the constraint of any view.

So your block of code could be transformed into this:

```
let ratio = CGFloat(image.width) / CGFloat(image.height)
userContentImageViewHeightConstraint.constant = CGFloat((UIScreen.main.bounds.width) / ratio)
self.layoutIfNeeded()
self.userContentImageView.kf.indicatorType = .activity
self.userContentImageView.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: image.url), completionHandler: { (_, _, _, _) in })
```

OR BETTER YET, (I realized this is inside your cell):

Before you return your cell in `cellForRow` you do the adjustment of the constraints! I had a personal project before with same flow/logic as yours - random image sizes with network calls.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        self.feedCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: self.feedCell.identifier)
            as! FeedTableViewCell
        self.feedCell.indexPath = indexPath
        self.feedCell.delegate = self

        let post = self.catPosts[indexPath.row]
        self.feedCell.post = post

        let aspectRatio = self.feedCell.getAspectRatioAccordingToiPhones(cellImageFrame: self.feedCell.frame.size, media: post.media!.first!)
        self.feedCell.constraint_PostHeight?.update(offset: aspectRatio)

        return self.feedCell
    }
```

and inside my cell, I have my `getAspectRadio....` method:

```
func getAspectRatioAccordingToiPhones(cellImageFrame: CGSize, media: Media) -> CGFloat {

        guard let widthNumber = NumberFormatter().number(from: catMedia.width!),
            let heightNumber = NumberFormatter().number(from: catMedia.height!) else {
            return UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        }

        let imageWidth = CGFloat(truncating: widthNumber)
        let imageHeight = CGFloat(truncating: heightNumber)

        let widthOffset = imageWidth - cellImageFrame.width
        let widthOffsetPercentage = (widthOffset * 100) / imageWidth
        let heightOffset = (widthOffsetPercentage * imageHeight) / 100
        let effectiveHeight = imageHeight - heightOffset
        return effectiveHeight
    }
```

I hope this helps out you now :) Good luck!

Comment: Just move on and dont care about the arrogants. They are the reason why ppl dont wanna put question on the stackoverflow. Problem maybe easy for them but not for anyone else.
Btw, read my question thoroughtfully before making any answer. Thanks for read.

Comment: Right. Thanks! I edited my whole answer. Check it out. @QuangLuu